# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in "with open" command

Tags: python, excel, encryption, directory

I need to access multiple password protected .xls files. They are all in one folder.

I first want to find all relevant files depending on the file ending and then select depending on how the filename starts with

The first part works and I get the displayed all .xls files in that folder, as well as the second part where I search for a specific filename. Now, when trying to open the encrypted file (I am using msoffcrypto)

I only want to open the encrypted "EXAMPLE_File"

I get the FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

complete code:

```
import msoffcrypto
import io
import pandas as pd
import os


decrypted = io.BytesIO()

# check what files are in the folder
path = "/Users/PATH/Desktop/Workspace/Projects"
list_of_directory = os.listdir(path)


# start looping through each file
for files in list_of_directory:
    # get all files that end with ".xls"
    if files.endswith(".xls"):
        # print(files)
        # get all files that start with "EXAMPLE_File"
        if files.startswith("EXAMPLE_File"):
            # print(files)
            # open password protected .xls
            with open(files, 'r') as f:
                excel = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
                excel.load_key('001234')
                excel.decrypt(decrypted)

df = pd.read_excel(decrypted)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

`files` will only be the name of the file, which your commented out `print(files)` should have made clear.  It must be joined with the `path`; otherwise, `open` will be looking in the current directory only.

For example, use:

```
fullname = os.path.join(path, files)
...
with open(fullname, 'rb') as f:
    ...
```

You can also use a more direct approach with [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), which will generate files that match a directory/file pattern:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('/Users/PATH/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/*.xls'):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Mark, appreciate it the quick response. I added your hint to my code. But I'm now getting a different error --> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @Freymi Use `'rb'` when opening the file.  XLS files are not text files so should be opened in binary mode.  The default text mode tries to decode the file's bytes using a default encoding...in this case UTF-8, but it isn't a UTF-8-encoded text file.